# Make Series hide and show by clicking on AmChart4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to implement [this](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-legend-to-show-only-one-graph-on-click/) on `AmChart4`

Showing only one graph by clicking legend marker.

It uses `clickMarker` / `clickLabel` though, AmChart4 doesn't have these property.

So I can get legend click event according to this [page](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/)

```
  chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    console.log("Clicked on", ev.target);
    console.log(chart);
  });
```

And now how can I get the series of charts and hide/show??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the series name from `ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.name`, which is documented further down in the same page. You can use that and loop through the chart series array and call `show()` or `hide()` as needed on matching/non-matching series, similar to the v3 demo:

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  var selectedSeries = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.name;
  chart.series.each(function(series) {
    if (series.name === selectedSeries) {
      series.show();
    }
    else {
      series.hide();
    }
  })
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/97c095f2496fcf52936f738e3f2101d3/)